# Problem with INSERT function

Tags: insert, smallsql

I use this function `INSERT` (http://www.smallsql.de/doc/sql-functions/string/insert.html) to add a value in a data:

```
INSERT (log, POSITION(' edited' IN log), 1, 'NOW()')
```

I use also the `NOW` function to add the date in the data but it does not work. What is the problem?

Comment: Why cant you use mysql or postgresql?
Its the first time av heard of smallsql!

Comment: it's used in an update request with my sql. I think the error is in the now () function after test but how can i correct it

Comment: is there a date() function? whats the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: NOW() is a function (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_now.asp). if i delete NOW() to my request the data is updated else i have a syntax error

Comment: @Amirov: `now()` is **not** a standard (ANSI) SQL function. You should not believe w3schools, that site is full of errors.

Comment: Btw: if you are looking for a small, embeddable Java DBMS you should probably have a look at HSQLDB or H2. Both are under active development and are much more "complete" than SmallSQL

Answer (score 1):

When you write your INSERT query:

```
INSERT (log, POSITION(' edited' IN log), 1, 'NOW()')
```

In this way the DBMS thinks you try to put in your date field a string named "NOW()" instead of function to retrieve the current timestamp

You must remove the ' ' around NOW() function. In this way:

```
INSERT (log, POSITION(' edited' IN log), 1, NOW())
```